# Google Earth Engine scale definition and export

Tags: coordinate-system, r, google-earth-engine, wgs84

I am trying to download Global Surface Water (Pekel et al 2016) data from Google Earth Engine. It has a specified maximum spatial resolution of 30 [presumably meters]. When I export the data specifying a scale of 30, it exports by default with a coordinate reference system of WGS 84. [According to this question Landsat is not in WGS 84 and a scale shouldn't be specified, but as was pointed out this is a requirement to export data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257490/exporting-an-image-in-google-earth-engine-image-alignment/257647#257647), but regardless, you need to specify a scale when exporting the image. A copy of this code is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff712a6c71c484aa169d2ce63ac9aa01?noload=1) (for reproducibility). I do this, and load up the image in R, and am told this:

```
 image <- raster("~/GSW_new/so_carolina_test.tif")
> image
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 850, 944, 802400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.0002694946, 0.0002694946  (x, y)
extent      : -81.10574, -80.85134, 32.14828, 32.37735  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : ~\GSW_new\so_carolina_test.tif 
names       : so_carolina_test 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

Indicating that the spatial resolution has been given in degrees (not meters...) and now I am not actually getting things out with fixed distances (only fixed degree distances). Worse, this doesn't match the degree spacing that's given by some of the imagery given from a separate source (.00025 by .00025): see the [data documentation](https://global-surface-water.appspot.com/download) with a specific example [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/global-surface-water/downloads/occurrence/occurrence_70E_80N.tif), but it is the stated nominal resolution outputted from:

```
var grabscale = grab.projection().nominalScale();
```

Additionally putting that downloaded file into ArcGIS yields the following (see screenshot). Note a resolution of 27 m - in northern latitudes this is distorted....
[image]

My understanding is that landsat data is at 30 m, and this dataset is projected in WGS84.

How can I download said 30 m data, and how can I download it over areas at 60 N or 70 N (Arctic) while accurately preserving the "30-m" resolution?

I need to accurately measure distances from water bodies, so I need accurate distance spacing.

Should I be doing CRS reprojection to UTM (my field site is approximately  62°38'56.60"N, 164° 5'40.35"W or can I download accurate data from GEE and do processing offline in R or ArcGIS?

Is the data, being in a WGS84 projection with equal spacing, no longer at 30-m resolution in the x-y directions?

**EDIT**
To clarify this question: Tyler Erickson noted that the dataset is in WGS84 projection, with nominal 30 m resolution at the equator. I am trying acquire the finets spatial resolution GSW dataset, and as noted above they provide their data at .00025 deg spacing while the "30 m" data from GEE is at a slightly coarser resolution. *How can I, using GEE, obtain the .00025 degree spacing that is provided by the GSW developers?* As part of the answer, it would be very helpful to include information (even links etc. for self-study) on how exactly these calculations are made so I can interpret these things more easily in the future. For example is this a basic formula concerning the distance between lines of latitude?

Pekel et al 2016: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature20584

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JRC Monthly Water History](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_0_MonthlyHistory) dataset is an image that uses a single coordinate reference system (CRS) of [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/), and does not use the same CRS as Landsat images (which use a collection of UTM zone spatial references). The 30m resolution refers to the nominal resolution at the projection origin (the equator in the case of EPSG:4326).

You can use Earth Engine to [export images](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-images) in a variety of CRSs, and each CRS/projection will [distort](http://geoawesomeness.com/map-distortions/) the map differently. For buffering lakes by small distances, a [conformal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Conformal) projection (such as Mercator) will have minimal distance distortion.

Comment: Tyler, I am accepting your answer but am at a bit of a loss on the spatial resolution of the dataset itself and perhaps this question is better suited for USGS or the authors: If Landsat is acquiring data at 30 m resolution, that is 30-m x 30-m pixels on the ground independent of latitude. How is the GSW in WGS84 coordinates giving data at finer than 30-m resolution: is it because in fact landsat is finer than 30-m in the north or because its been downscaled/resampled to 10-m. If so how was it resampled to 10-m?

Comment: Tyler, I've updated the question (under Edit) and need ab it more from your answer to accept it - specifically how to get the degree spacing provided by the GSW authors on their website from the GEE, which uses meters/pix as the resolution specification.